# How to create CrmServiceClient instance in .Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dynamics-crm

I tried this code:

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector;

var connectionString = @"AuthType = Office365; 
                         Url = https://myorg.api.crm8.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc;Username=user@azureresulticks.onmicrosoft.com;Password=***";

CrmServiceClient conn = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);

IOrganizationService service;
```

but I'm getting this error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

on trying to create the `CrmServiceClient` instance.

The same piece of code was working in .NET framework versions.

But this time, I have to use .NET Core.

Comment: Looks like CrmServiceClient is not supported on dotnet core. You can use the [CDM SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client), since it uses dotnet core and supports Dynamics CRM 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly` is a NuGet package built on .NET Framework 4.6.2. It is not compatible with .NET Core.

When connecting with Dynamics 365 CE from a .NET Core project, try package `Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client`. It is pretty new and designed for .NET Core and Dynamics 365 Online.

See also:

- [Dataverse Service Client is now Generally Available - MS PowerApps blog](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/dataverse-service-client-is-now-generally-available/)
- [Transition apps to Dataverse ServiceClient - MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/sdk-client-transition)
- [Reference documentation - MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powerplatform.dataverse.client?view=dataverse-sdk-latest)
- [Sample code - GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerApps-Samples/tree/master/dataverse/orgsvc/C%23-NETCore/ServiceClient)